# Scheduled Task history empty despite Task getting started and ending normally?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2016

I've a windows 2016 Server where I have a multitude of Scheduled Tasks running on it. For a handful of the tasks I suddenly have the problem that the History tab is ALWAYS empty (despite having all tasks history enabled in the actions).

The tasks can be started normally and execute and end normally, but the history stays empty.

My question is here naturally WHY? Thus what can I do to correct this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some reasons for history not being displayed for some tasks:

- The task names contain special characters, even such as the simple `&`
- The Event Log overflowed and was emptied
- Some internal mixup with Task Scheduler. This can usually be fixed by disabling
  history and then re-enabling it again (requires starting Task Scheduler as Admin).

Comment: tried the disablinng and reenabling already, no effect sadly. But an & is in the name.tnx!

Comment: There's nothing like too much beer, and digging thru the registry... lol